# Change the Config file in Remote file using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application which is connecting http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x/login.aspx.

From My local machine i can use the url to browse the appliation and there is config file which is in Remote machine basically controls the application.

All my scripts are written on my local. My suite runs on my local machine. I just wanted to change the paramter (eg., timeout) and verify the front end app gets effected.

I can not run the suite on VM which has very limited access. so i have to run the selenium suite from my local.

So is there any possible way to connect the host and change the config file using Java

Comment: not unless there is an API to do so.

Comment: Api which needs to be written on own??

Comment: The server code will have to allow update of the config file through some API.  Otherwise it would not be very secure would it.

Comment: It will allow me if i login on the remote machine, i am gonna use the same username and password... would it not allow from api??